# Some questions concerning the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $a_n$ be the number of permutations in $S_n$ having an square root.

1. Is it true that $a_{2n+1} = (2n+1)a_{2n}$ ? (experimental data's shows that this is true for small values of $n$).
2. Is there any formula expressing $a_n$ in terms of $n$?
3. Among all elements of $S_n$ which ones has the most number of square roots and what is this max value ?

Comment: This may help to check whether your counting is correct: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-root-of-permutation.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence $a_n$ you are referring is listed in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences:

[OEIS: A003483](http://oeis.org/A003483)

The entry gives the following information:

1. It is indeed true that $a_{2n+1} = (2n+1)a_{2n}$.
2. There does not seem to be a closed-form formula for $a_n$, although the entry does give a closed-form formula for the [exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function).
3. The entry also gives an asymptotic estimate of the form $\displaystyle a_n \sim C \frac{n!}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $C$ is a certain constant.

Incidentally, observe that a permutation in $S_n$ has a square root if and only if its cycle decomposition has an even number of cycles of each even length.  This follows immediately from the fact that the square of a $k$-cycle is a $k$-cycle if $k$ is odd, and is a pair of disjoint $(k/2)$-cycles if $k$ is even.

**Edit:** By the way, does anyone know a simple argument that $a_{2n+1} = (2n+1)a_{2n}$?  This isn't obvious to me.

Comment: I have a vague memory of doing this in a generating functions class.  I think it was in [Wilf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) in Chapter 3 on the exponential formula.