# Problem on a square group

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a finite group.

An element $a \in  G$ is called a square if there exists $x \in G$ such
that $x^ 2 = a$.

Is the following statement(s) is/are true?

(A) If $a,b ∈ G$ are not squares, $ab$ is a square.

(B) Suppose that $G$ is cyclic. Then if $a,b ∈ G$ are not squares, $ab$ is a square

A very weird problem.Neither able to find counter examples nor able to prove it.What to do?

Comment: For A, you may want to use a characterization of squares in symmetric groups: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-root-of-permutation.

Comment: For a finite abelian group, it can be shown that the mapping $a \mapsto a^2$ is an isomorphism on the group.  Since cyclic groups are abelian it follows that every element in $G$ is a square. So part $B$ is vacuously true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a partial answer for the proof. part b. If G is cyclic generated by g and a is not a square, then we can find an integer k such that $a=g^{2k+1}$, and similarly we write $b=g^{2q+1}$, $ab=g^{2k+1+2q+1}=g^{2(k+q+1)}=(g^{k+q+1})^{2}$.

Comment: made a slight edit. Hope you don’t mind.

Comment: For part a, I am trying to look for a counterexample in the dihedral group of order 8 , actiong on the square whose vertices are labeled  1 2 3 4 counterclockwise. I think the symmtry (14)(23) is not a square in this group, and neither is the symmetry (24). (24)(14)(23)=(1234), which might not be a square

Comment: @Lubin there's no problem at all. It looks nicer now.

Comment: excellent part b; small and concise+1

Answer (score 7):

When working with additive notation being a square can be translated to being even (being the sum of an element with itself)

Part $A$:

Take $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ with additive notation.

$(1,0)$ is not a square since $(0,0)$ is the only square (adding an element to itself gives $(0,0)$

$(0,1)$ is not a square.

$(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)$ is not a square, so it is false.

---

Part $B$:

Notice that this is true in $\mathbb Z$ (sum of odd numbers is even). Since all infinite cyclics are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ we are done.

We now go to $\mathbb Z_n$.

if $n$ is odd then every element is a "square" since if $m$ is even $m$ then $m=\frac{m}{2}+\frac{m}{2}$ (where by $\frac{m}{2}$ I mean actually taking the integer $\frac{m}{2}$ and then considering the residue class). On the other hand if $m$ is odd then $n+m$ is even and so we can do the same thing, taking into account in $\mathbb Z_n$ $m$ and $n+m$ are the same thing.

If $n$ is even then the "squares" are exactly the elements that are even, this is because reducing a number $\bmod$ an even modulus preserves the parity, in this case we just use that odd plus odd is even, and so the sum of two non-squares is a square.

Comment: part a is very good but I will go with @mich for part b +1

Answer (score 3):

Notice that in any abelian group $G$, the set of squares $S$ is a subgroup, since $x^2y^2=(xy)^2$. In fact, it is a normal subgroup (since all subgroups are normal in abelian groups), which means we can consider the quotient group $G/S$ of multiplication of cosets. One can quickly take that:

> A cyclic group is generated by one element. Let $x$ be such an element. The quotient $G/S$ must also be generated by one element, call it $y$. Since all squares are in $S$, it follows that $y^2=e$. Thus $G/S$ is either the cyclic group on two elements or the trivial group.

From there, we have that if $x$ and $y$ are non-squares, they are in the same coset of $S$ (since there are at most two cosets, one being $S$ itself). This coset has order two hence squares to $S$ - in particular, meaning that $xy$ is a square.

If we have an abelian group of more than one generator (for instance, in $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$), then the quotient $G/S$ can have more than one generator - meaning non-square $x$ and $y$ might not belong to the same coset and the product of the cosets might not be $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Another counter example for part $A$:

Consider $Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$.  Here $i$ and $j$ are not squares, because any $x \in Q_8$ satisfies either $x^2=1$ or $x^2=-1$ .  Also $ij=k$ is not a square!