# How to find a permutation $\sigma$ given the permutation $\sigma^2$?

Tags: permutations

How to solve the equation:

$\sigma ^2 =\left({\begin{array}{*{20}c}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5\end{array}}\right)\  $ where $\sigma \in S_5$.

Is there a general method?

Comment: Have you tried to find a cycle decomposition?

Comment: I think a general method might be hard, since $\sigma$ does not have to be unique, e.g. repeating the swapping of two elements is equivalent to doing nothing.

Comment: I think this answer your question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-root-of-permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can write $\sigma^2=(243)$. Thus, being $\sigma\in S_5$, the only possibilities are
$$
\sigma=(234)
$$
and
$$
\sigma=(15)(234)\;\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints (corrected): Note that your permutation $\sigma^{2}$ has odd order. In general, a permutation $\tau$ of odd order $n$ has a square root which is $\tau^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$, though this is not usually unique. However, you should check out for yourself that you understand why this is so, and not just take my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may wonder what happens to a single permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, represented as a product of disjoint cycles, when we square it: any cycle of odd length gives a cycle of the same length, any cycle of length $2m$ breaks as the product of two cycles of length $m$. By reversing the process, we may see that an element in $S_n$ is a square iff its cycles of even length come in pairs, and
$$ (1)(5)(2\,4\,3)\in S_5 $$
is the square of $(1\,5)(2\,3\,4)$ or the square of $(1)(5)(2\,3\,4)$. In general, the number of square roots, provided that one exists, is $2^m$, where $m$ is the number of couples of cycles of the same length.