# Find number of square permutations

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

Let's call a permutation a **square** if it is a product of some other permutation with itself.

> For a given $n$, find the number of square permutations.

**Attempt**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-root-of-permutation) explains that a permutation has a square root if and only if the number of cycles of same even length in its representation is even (or zero). But how do we calculate the number of permutations with such a property?

Comment: The problem is not so obvious... have a look at [this paper](http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/45/ajc_v45_p037.pdf).

Comment: There is an EGF at [Wikipedia on random permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Permutations_that_are_squares).

Comment: Cheating: http://oeis.org/A003483