# Equation with permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

I have the following equation with permutations :

$x^2=(1 2 3)(4)$

I try to solve this by direct method with repeted tries, after i tested it's compatibility with the signature of the permutation, there is a better way to find the unknown permutation x? Something like the inverse of the permutation? Imention that the permutation in the right is given in cycle form :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 
 2& 3 & 1 &4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Rotating a triangle clockwise twice is the same as rotating it counterclockwise once.  For your specific problem, note that $(132)^2=(123)$.  For the more general case of finding a square root of a permutation see the linked problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the square root of a permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-square-root-of-a-permutation)