# Requirement for an even permutation to be a square

Tags: permutation-cycles

Given an even permutation $\sigma,$ what more is required for it to be the square of some other permutation? Is it enough that there be an even number of transpositions in its cycle decomposition?

I looked at the case $\sigma=(12)(3456)$ and could not find a squareroot for that, or others I tried having an odd number of transpositions in their decompositions.

I would be interested in any specific counterexample having an odd number of transpositions, and also whether more is required for a permutation to be a square.

Comment: If you have the cycle decomposition of a permutation, try to figure out the cycle decomposition of its square.

Comment: @user8268 I did that and it suggested what I conjectured about the cycle decomposition needing an even number of transpositions. However I wasn't myself sure, and also wondered about whether more conditions were needed to guarantee a permutation is a square.

Comment: your condition is necessary but not sufficient. There is a similar condition for other cycles of even length.

Comment: You might try thinking about squares and square roots of single cycles.

Comment: To moderators: The following shows my question is a duplicate. Maybe it can be labelled as such in order for it not to remain open. [comments here already answer it.] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266569/how-to-find-the-square-root-of-a-permutation